How to unzip a file using JavaScript that is in base64 format
I have base64 string that is a zip file. I need to extract the file the zip file and to do so I was trying to utilize a library noted in an answer here on Stack Overflow called fflate:
  attachmentsFlat.forEach(async (attachment) => {
  attachment = await emailStore.getAttachment(props.mailbox, attachment.email_id, attachment.id)
  if(attachment.file_name.split('.').pop() ==  'zip') {

    const decompressed = fflate.decompressSync(attachment.content_bytes);
    console.log(decompressed)
  }

However, this results in an error:
fflate.js?v=2017d673:285 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dat.subarray is not a function
at inflt (fflate.js?v=2017d673:285:21)
at inflateSync (fflate.js?v=2017d673:1103:10)
at Module.decompressSync (fflate.js?v=2017d673:1421:160)
at EmailFilesAssignment.vue:150:37

If this library does not work I am open to other libraries that can take base64 and unzip the files. I just cannot find many example of unzip files but more so zipping and using base64 is a special example I cannot find.
I also attempted to do this via JSZip but I am unsure how to get the files out asynchronously. I have tried the following:
attachmentsFlat.forEach(async (attachment) => {
  attachment = await emailStore.getAttachment(props.mailbox, attachment.email_id, attachment.id)
  if(attachment.file_name.split('.').pop() ==  'zip') {
    const zipFiles = await uncompressZipAttachment(attachment)
    console.log(zipFiles) // shows [] and 8 entries in console
    console.log(zipFiles[0]) //always returns undefined
  }
})
  const dataURLtoFile = (base64String: string, contentType: string | undefined, filename: string) => {
        let mime = contentType
        let bstr = atob(base64String) 
        let n = bstr.length
        let u8arr = new Uint8Array(n)
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}

  const uncompressZipAttachment = async (attachment : FileAttachment) : Promise<any> => {
    let files : File[] = []
    const decompressedZipFiles = await jsZip.loadAsync(dataURLtoFile(attachment.content_bytes, attachment.content_type, attachment.file_name))
    decompressedZipFiles.forEach(async (filename) => {
      let fileData = await decompressedZipFiles.files[filename].async("blob"); 
      files.push(new File([fileData], filename))
    })
    return files
  }


"I have base64 string that is a zip file" — do you mean that you have a zipped file, and when it's unzipped the contents of the file is a base64 string?

I am downloading attachments from MS Graph API. I convert the attachments to base64 and some of these attachments are zip files. So the zip files are already encoded in base64. I am so close to getting the files created from jszip but for some reason i cannot access the file objects. See my example above trying to read to console. Always returns undefined although there are 8 files.

I dont understand why console.log(zipFiles) could show 8 entries but you cannot access the individual ones by console.log(zipFiles[0]). Can an array of file objects not be access individually similar to a normal array of object?

If you simply do decompressedZipFiles.forEach(async ...  it won't wait for everything before return files. So indeed zipFiles is [] and zipFiles[0] undefined when you console.log it, but after you logged it, the contents were pushed so that when you click "expand" button to show the contents of zipFiles it has 8 elements. I suspect the problem can be solved by doing let promises = decompressedZipFiles.map(async (filename) => ... followed by await Promise.all(promises) before return files.

Yes but shouldnt await make the caller wait to call the console.log() line until the await is completed which should have all the data then?

The await of let fileData = await ... only applies to async (filename) => {... part and not the async (attachment :FileAttachment) due to function scopes

So there is only one attachment in the email. It is a zip file with 8 docs inside of it. So the await then console should have the full collection of 8 docs before it gets to it. Unless await/async doesnt work like it does in c#?

I'm not familiar with C#, but it is possible that different programing languages define their behaviors of await differently. Anyway, if you used for(let filename of decompressedZipFiles){  instead of an arrow function, then the await is applied to the async (attachment: FileAttachment) function, and it happens one after another (scope again), not in parallel.

The way you had it was like decompressedZipFiles.forEach(someOtherFunctionReturningPromise) in which case JS is really not going to wait for it, just like if you do someOtherFunctionReturningPromise(file1); someOtherFunctionReturningPromise(file2); the tasks for file1 and file2 are just queued and the async (attachment : FileAttachment) ... function continues with the next instruction(s), which is return files in this case. So indeed it returns the empty array BUT there are tasks to push contents later, which is why the contents include 8 entries when you expand in the browser console.

I still am struggling to understand the async/await you mention. So in C# if I had a loop and inside that loop had an async function but put await it will not go to the next loop until the await line occured. So in javascript are you saying the foreach(async ()=>{}) keeps looping through each object despite there is an await inside {} ? Also, does await Promise.All() only catch the first layer of promises it maps or does it await even the nested ones as well so you do not have to nest await Promise.All like I did above?

Yes, in JS things like forEach(async ()=>{...}) indeed keep on going through each call without waiting for the previous call to finish, as async ()=>{...} is considered a different anynomous function. It's just like having an external function and use it like forEach(some_external_function) except for variable access. It's comparable to how, having a return will not affect the outer function, and only the part inside async ()... is stopped. However, if you have for (...){ await ...} or for await ... it will wait (as there is no new function created).

And if you had for (...) { return;} it would stop the current function, however forEach( () => { if(something){ return; } do_something(); } the return will only stop the inner function, the outer one will continue execution. As for await Promise.all(some_array), well, it depends on what you mean by "first layer", but if every element of some_array is handled properly then it will wait for all of them, if some fails then it fails. If you want examples unrelated to the current question thread, we can continue in chat.
